# Wi-Fi: no hardware installed

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, snow-leopard

WiFi on my **MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010)** has stopped working.

When I click the WiFi button I see the message "Wi-Fi: no hardware installed"
[image: Wi-Fi: no hardware installed]

I have attempted many things, including other questions in this StackExchange site ([this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277153/macbook-is-displaying-the-message-no-hardware-installed-when-i-click-on-wi-fi) was the first answer I found and I followed but didn't solve my issue. Ultimately it suggests replacing my Airport card, but I'd rather eliminate all software/logic possibilities before getting to replacing the Airport adapter or buying a USB wifi adapter).

The detailed steps I've taken:

**- MOVING/DELETING SystemConfiguration**

I've followed [this answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7754188?answerId=7754188021#7754188021) to check whether my en1 (airport adapter) exist and was working:

`ifconfig -a` - it showed up

`ifconfig en1 inet up` or `ifconfig en1 up` - both resulted in the same error: **interface en1 does not exist'**

Then I moved/deleted the files located at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfigurations` as instructed.

1. Removed the `preferences.plist` and restarted. Since it didn't resolve I continued.
2. Removed `NetworkInterfaces.plist & com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` and restarted.
3. Lastly, I attempted to remove the whole `SystemConfiguration` folder, but Mac didn't allow it. So I removed as many files as possible and restarted. Didn't resolve the problem, but en1 disappeared for good from `System Preferences -> Network`.

**- NVRAM & SMC reset**

Followed several guides, but ultimately this one and it didn't work.
I have reset NVRAM & SMC countless times.

**- AHT**

Some guides suggest running Apple Hardware Test.
I've tried, but it doesn't work, returns the error **-3403D**: as I've researched, it means AHT can't be run in my system.

**QUESTIONS**

Backing up and reformatting has any chance to resolve the problem? Is it worthy of trying? Any other suggestions?
I'm considering to buy an USB wifi adapter.

As a last resort and hoping that my airport adapter is still working and not faulty, I'm asking here.

**SYSTEM INFO**

MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2010)

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

**NETWORK WINDOW**
[image: wifi screen]

Comment: Welcome on board. 1st thing 1st: the trick of resetting NVRAM & SMC is just a trick or a religion if you prefer. It can't fix anything about Wi-Fi problem. Just note the sources who gave you this advice to avoid them in the future.

Comment: @dan, yeah, the more I saw those advices, the more ineffective they seemed.

Comment: Try rebooting while holding down the "d" key to enter diagnostics mode and see what that says, or is that what you referred to as "AHT?". I doubt that it is an OS issue at this point as the card is detected by the OS. But if you have the time it wouldn't *hurt*  to wipe and reinstall, though I am doubtful this is an OS issue. And I hate to say it but it **is** a 10 year old computer. The WiFi components may have just died.

Comment: @SteveChambers: I share your analysis, this isn't an OS issue since the time 10.13.6 was produced all the quality controls have been made by the users. I think the culprit is the brave old Wi-Fi cable and its cheap socket connector.

Comment: @dan is absolutely correct about resetting NVRAM and the SMC - both are unrelated to this issue.  The next myth is "reinstalling macOS."  This is a **major** procedure and should only be done as a last resort.  There's [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) and [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) that basically boots a clean version of macOS - if it fails in these, reinstalling likewise will have no effect

Comment: @SteveChambers, yes, Steve, I've tried to bot holding 'd' key (refer to AHT). As of reinstall OS, I don't know how to do it. I've never did it before. If I was to do it, I'd need some advice to avoid data loss, and incorrect reformatting.

Comment: To improve your question and start an analysis on the right track, I'd suggest to open ` > About This Mac > System Preferences… > System Report… > Network > Wi-Fi`, make a screen capture and include it within your original question (OQ).

Comment: I've updated it, @dan

Comment: As https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277153/macbook-is-displaying-the-message-no-hardware-installed-when-i-click-on-wi-fi implies: This is a HW issue.